# Oracle - Treat join on NULL as true

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which I have to join on 4 columns:

```
SELECT columns 
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON o.col1 = ot.col1 
    AND o.col2 = ot.col2 
    AND o.col3 = ot.col3 
    AND o.col4 = ot.col4
```

However, if any of the columns in other_table is null I would like to evaluate the join condition as true regardless of the value of the other column from t, for example if ot.col4 IS NULL for given row then evaluate only col1, col2 and col3 conditions when joining.

Any ideas?

Comment: You know you can write any condition you want, like: `AND (o.col4 = ot.col4 OR ot.col4 IS NULL)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT columns 
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON o.col1 = NVL(ot.col1, o.col1)
    AND o.col2 = NVL(ot.col2, o.col2)
    AND o.col3 = NVL(ot.col3, o.col3)
    AND o.col4 = NVL(ot.col4, o.col4)
```

Comment: So simple, I feel dumb now... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columns 
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON o.col1 = nvl(ot.col1,t.col1) 
    AND o.col2 = nvl(ot.col2, t.col2)
    AND o.col3 = nvl(ot.col3, t.col3)
    AND o.col4 = nvl(ot.col4, t.col4)
```